# cart.php queries are slow and speed fluctuates

Tags: prestashop

When I analyze page speed on my website, I sometimes get a quite long loading time just for cart.php. (400ms+) I do not have many products or categories. I understand that there are a lot of fields being joined / fetched from the database, but I do not know why the load speed of cart.php is so variable. If anyone has experienced the same problem or managed to solve it, please let me know.

I am using Prestashop 1.4.9

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that my theme had installed a second cart module, which slowed things up.
Disabled one of them and the speed was a lot better.